# css3 margin shrink on mouse over / hover

Tags: html, css

OK,

So I have a "3d" button in css with :hover transition.

Here's the html

```
<nav>
<ul class="hmenu">
    <li><a href="">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="">Item 1</a></li>
    <li><a href="">Item 2</a></li>
    <li><a href="">Item 3</a></li>
</ul>
</nav>
```

And here's the css

```
ul.hmenu {
margin-top: 9%;
z-index: 50;
width: 75%;
list-style: none;
}

ul.hmenu li {
float: left;
margin-left: 5%;
}

ul.hmenu li a:before {
content: "\2022\00a0";
color: #f00;
transition: color 1s ease;
}

ul.hmenu li a {
background: #333;
color: #fff;
display: block;
font: normal 100 1.5em Helvetica, sans;
padding: .5em;
box-shadow: 5px 5px 0 0 #f00;
transition: background-color 1s ease;
text-decoration: none;    
}

ul.hmenu li a:hover, ul.hmenu li a:active {
background-color: #f00;
box-shadow: none;
transform: translate(5px, 5px);
}

ul.hmenu li a:hover:before, ul.hmenu li a:active:before {
color: #fff;
content: "\203A\00a0";  
}
```

And here's the JSFIDDLE: http://jsfiddle.net/etb6F/

My question is, how can I prevent the buttons from moving slightly to the left when on :hover? I want them to maintain their position, just to "press down" but not move left.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the transform, you also have to keep the `li` fixed width and height so that the other buttons aren't affected.

DEMO: http://jsfiddle.net/etb6F/3/

Exact fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/etb6F/4/

Comment: thanks, the LI's were missing a size constraint. even % size works!

Answer (score 0):

On Line 30: in the `ul.hmenu li a:hover, ul.hmenu li a:active {}` section, remove the first instance of 5px. You should use this:

```
ul.hmenu li a:hover, ul.hmenu li a:active {
    background-color: #f00;
    box-shadow: none;
    transform: translate(0, 5px);
}
```

The first number in `translate(X,Y)` moves it along the X-axis, and the second number (Y) moves it along the Y-axis.

Comment: I think OP is looking for a press effect.

Comment: @fizzydrink I'm sorry, but that's just not possible, unless you have other code that you didn't include in your JSFiddle. There is zero code in the JSFiddle link you provided that moves anything laterally (which means side-to-side) except for the `5px` that I changed to `0`. Or if you mean something other than the button.

Comment: @fizzydrink Or do you mean the red background? http://jsfiddle.net/TylerH/etb6F/5/ Which is not moving laterally but actually being removed. I've added it back and set it to move vertically only in this JSFiddle.

Comment: @TylerH I meant to say, that I want it to be like a button, however, what I had tried moved it laterally.

Answer (score 0):

replace: `transform: translate(5px, 5px);`
with: `margin:5px -5px -5px 5px;`